# Instafeed JavaScript Issue

Tags: javascript, instagram

So I've downloaded the `instafeed.min.js` file onto my machine. I am trying to include it in my HTML file and I do so as such:

```
<script src ="instafeed.min.js", type = "text/javascript">
```

Which should be correct as both the JavaScript file and my HTML file are both in the same directory. However, when I run this script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'friday',
    clientId: 'bbababfbc6cf42d9bdd731488f99303a'
       });
     feed.run();
</script>
```

No instagram photos show up on the site.  I've followed tutorials and registered a new client via Instagram's Developer website. My question is for the URL needed to register a new client: am I allowed to put in my local host address as the website URL? If not, perhaps that is why my `clientId` isn't working.

EDIT:: I also used the respective `div` :

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the respect div for it?

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

UPDATE:

Looks like Instagram validates the domain you are, so try uploading your files to the production environment.

Another thing, make sure jQuery is loaded. The documentation says that you don't need, but i got some errors without it.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.lukej.me/instafeed.js/1.2.0/instafeed.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            var feed = new Instafeed({
                get: 'tagged',
                tagName: 'cats',
                useHttp: true,
                clientId: 'your-client-id-here '
            });
            feed.run();
          });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="instafeed"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I also added the respective div

Comment: It should,I registered my application through the Instagram API and received a clientId. However, on the site : https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/,  I listed my local host as my website URL. Not sure if that is what's causing the problem

Comment: yeah, looks like the validate the domain. i would say to upload the files to the production environment and run there.

Comment: another thing: make sure you have loaded jquery. the documentation says that you don't need to, but on my tests i needed that. i got this working, will update the answer.

Comment: @DeseanAbraham, i've updated the answer within a working code.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`<script src="instafeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

instead of using `<style>`.

The `<style>`-tag is for in-file css rules, not for Javascript. Also, `<style>` does not have a `src`-attribute. To include external stylesheets in your html, use

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/my.css" />`

Comment: sorry, I meant to write <script> . That was a typo in the post. The code has this correct but still does not execute.